# Is the Ethereum Subtleties page correct about value transfers under exceptions?

Tags: evm, out-of-gas, exceptions, yellow-paper

On the Ethereum [Subtleties page](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties) (largely maintained by VB) it states the following under [Exceptional Conditions](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties#exceptional-conditions):

> - If a transaction triggers an exception, then:
>
>   - The value transfer from sender to recipient still takes place

This doesn't match my understanding, my tests or, I think, the [Yellow Paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) which says in section 8 (my emphasis),

> if the execution halts in an exceptional fashion (i.e. due to an
>   exhausted gas supply, stack underflow, invalid jump destination or
>   invalid instruction)... the state is reverted to the point
>   *immediately prior to balance transfer*

Interestingly, chriseth added [a notice](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties/_compare/96a7b5c3877c988a1eab6f43053b6c660a50a520...fb19475ffc624172410f9ce809eac2945349d327) in Feb 16 to the effect that some things about reverting Ether transactions were wrong. This notice was [removed](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties/_compare/fb19475ffc624172410f9ce809eac2945349d327...0151ff61dd587a4339fbc92421462f4c3a8ab5b6) in June 17 by vbuterin.

So, is the Subtleties paper just incorrect on this, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, Vitalik updated what he believed to be the totality of the subtleties and removed the notice added by Chris.

The lines that you note were not changed.

I also agree that this is incorrect, and as such suspect that this was simply an oversight. I have tweeted Vitalik, and Chris - maybe they can comment?

Comment: Thanks. Once they've confirmed it's the case by updating the page I'll make this the accepted answer :-)

Comment: The cited section of the yellow paper is correct. Feel free to edit the wiki page :-)

Comment: Yoichi has made an update - I'm not sure I *understand* the update (he's added "sometimes"), but it's enough to close this question.